# In Idris, how to add 1 to a Fin until a "max" is Reached

Tags: enums, dependent-type, idris

I have a data type which takes a number in constructor, and this number MUST be between 1 and 5 (represented as 0..4):

```
import Data.Fin
data Stars = MkStars (Fin 5)
```

I want to create a function that add one to an existing `star`, and if it's  already a `5 stars`, doesn't do anything

I tried

```
addOneStar: Stars -> Stars
addOneStar (MkStars FZ) = MkStars (FS FZ)
addOneStar (MkStars (FS x)) = if x < 3 
                              then MkStars (FS (FS x)) 
                              else MkStars (FS x)
```

But it doesn't compile with the error :

```
Type mismatch between
            Fin 4 (Type of x)
    and
            Fin 3 (Expected type)

    Specifically:
            Type mismatch between
                    1
            and
                    0
```

Can someone explain to me why is there this error ? 
And How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fin` implements the `Enum` interface, providing the successor function `succ` with exactly the desired semantics, which makes the implementation of `addOneStar` trivial:

```
addOneStar: Stars -> Stars
addOneStar (MkStars s) = MkStars $ succ s
```

Answer (score 4):

[Cactus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38301215/1610268) explains the problem and gives one possible solution. Since we have dependent types in Idris, though, I would at least advertise the possibility of a solution that makes use of that and could thus be seen as more idiomatic:

```
nextFin : (m : Fin (S n)) -> {auto p : (toNat m) `LT` n} -> Fin (S n)
nextFin {n = Z} FZ {p} = absurd $ succNotLTEzero p
nextFin {n = Z} (FS FZ) impossible
nextFin {n = S k} FZ = FS FZ
nextFin {n = S k} (FS l) {p} = let p = fromLteSucc p in
  FS $ nextFin l
```

This function takes as argument a proof that the given `Fin` is not the last one. This way you can be sure on the level of the type checker that the program never even tries to give you a `nextFin` for that.

If you don't want that, but rather something akin to the cited answer, you can also use `strengthen` together with [`with` rules](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/views.html) to avoid most of the cases:

```
nextFin : Fin (S n) -> Maybe $ Fin (S n)
nextFin m with (strengthen m)
  | Left k = Nothing
  | Right k = Just $ FS k
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of the constructor `FS` is `FS : Fin n -> Fin (S n)`, so if you have `x : Fin 5`, even if you know it is less than `3 : Fin 5`, its type is still `Fin 5`, so you can't pass it to `FS` and get another `Fin 5`; you'll get a `Fin 6` instead.

You can write a function `nextFin : Fin n -> Maybe (Fin n)` that returns `Nothing` for the largest `Fin`; but that function has to rebuild the new `Fin`, it can't just apply `FS` at the topmost level. The idea is to use the fact that `FZ : Fin n` either has or doesn't have a successor depending on whether `n` is 1 or greater; and the successor of `FS k` is the successor of `k` wrapped in `FS`:

```
import Data.Fin

total nextFin : Fin n -> Maybe (Fin n)
nextFin {n = Z}         k      = absurd k
nextFin {n = (S Z)}     _      = Nothing
nextFin {n = (S (S n))} FZ     = Just (FS FZ)
nextFin {n = (S (S n))} (FS k) = map FS $ nextFin k
```

Comment: Why not just drop the `Maybe`?

Comment: @AndrásKovács: What would be the `nextFin` of the last `Fin`?

Comment: Yeah, but that's trivially recoverable as `fromMaybe k $ nextFin k` from my nextFin; it contains less information

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have addressed your question directly. I'm here to offer an alternative design.

You mention that your number must be between 1 and 5. (It looks like you're building some sort of movie rating system?) Rather than indirectly represent this as a bounded natural number between 0 and 4, why not just enumerate the small number of allowed cases directly? You don't need dependent types for this; the following is valid Haskell 98.

```
data Stars = OneStar
           | TwoStars
           | ThreeStars
           | FourStars
           | FiveStars
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Bounded, Enum)

addOneStar FiveStars = FiveStars
addOneStar s = succ s
```

Comment: In fact, I simplified the problem I were facing. The expected number is not between 1 and 5 but between 1 and 50, so it's not a very good idea to  enumerate each case.